# Значение и происхождение слова "сосуд"

Tags: этимология, лексика

1. Каково происхождение слова *сосуд*? Как это слово связано с *судом* (семантически)?
2. В "Евгении Онегине" А. С. Пушкина есть строки:

> Он верил, что друзья готовы
>   За честь его принять оковы,
>   И что не дрогнет их рука
>   *Разбить сосуд* клеветника.

Здесь *сосуд* употреблено в значении "оружие" (по комментариям Е. Ларионова). Откуда взялось это значение, и есть ли другие примеры его использования?

Answer (score 1):

Существует мнение о том, что сосуд употреблен в значении "оружие", но  не очень ясно, откуда это оружие взялось. [Роман А. С. Пушкина 'Евгений Онегин'. Комментарий (Лотман Ю.М.) | litena.ru](http://litena.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000013/st017.shtml)

С одной стороны, **сосуд ―  это метафора человека,** так что можно считать, что  друзья готовы уничтожить самого клеветника, но это слишком радикальное решение.

С другой стороны,  слова "суд и сосуд"  семантически связаны между собой, у них **общая этимология**. **Сосуд, посуда, судно, судок** ―  эти слова имеют значение вместилища, составленного из частей (приставка СО, глагол ДЕТЬ). И вот суд, судебное разбирательство ―  это тоже соединение, но в этом случае соединение различных мнений, связанных с  защитой и обвинением.

Поэтому **"сосуд" клеветника можно рассматривать как "суд" клеветника, составленный из клеветнических домыслов, сплетен и т.д.** ( по крайней мере, это мнение можно рассмотреть в качестве версии).

Answer (score 1):

Об этимологии уже сказали, а что до Пушкина,его строк

И что не дрогнет их рука

Разбить сосуд клеветника -

это метафора: тело - сосуд души.

Метафорика  образа многогранна и объемна, богатство поэтических вариаций заложено ещё в народной традиции,восходит и к христианству - к 18-й главе Книги пророка Иеремии, проповеди о восстановленном сосуде." И было слово Господне ко мне: не могу ли Я поступить с вами, дом Израилев, подобно горшечнику сему, говорит Господь. Вот что глина в руке горшечника, то вы в Моей руке».

Это же речь о Ленском, его мировоззрении романтика.

Он верил, что друзья готовы

За честь его принять оковы,

-явный намёк на стихотворение Шиллера "Порука", где друг спешил выручить друга-заложника, готового принять смерть за него.Ленский верил в истинную дружбу, в то, что настоящие друзья способны отомстить, убить клеветника.

Comment: Так всё-тки убить, лишить жизни?  А что по этому поводу думают авторитетные пушкиноведы? И откуда взялась версия об оружии, как Вы считаете? И еще интересно: эта метафора применялась раньше  (до Пушкина) в художественной литературе?

Comment: Версия об оружии взялась у Лотмана, помните такого советского пушкиноведа? Все у него переписывают, он атеист, но опирается на 7 Псалом 14 стих: у Бога на нераскаянных грешников приготовлено такое страшное оружие, которое поражает смертоносными стрелами, сделанными наподобие воспламеняющихся молниеносных стрел, от которых ни укрыться, ни отразить их ничем невозможно. Стрелы=сосуды смертные, кто- то переводит "сосуды со смертью" Переводчик из него никакой. Это развёрнутая метафора, а он переводит пословно. Стрелы здесь - орудие смерти = смерть ( на основе метонимии).

Comment: Получилось, сосуды - орудие, оружие.В Библейской энциклопедии Брокгауза Сосуд это:1) букв. знач.чаша, кувшин, и т.д. - вместилище; 2) в метафорич. значении  в Библии названы люди (Рим 9:22 и след.; 2Тим 2:20 и след.). "Сосудами гнева"названы люди неверующие, а "сосудами милосердия" - спасенные кровью Иисуса Христа. Во 2 Кор 4:7 Павел  называет тело человека С., в к-ром заключено сокровище Евангелия (см. Евангелие, благовествование), и потому этот С. становится жилищем Св. Духа .Сосуд скудельный- . Разг. Устар. Слабое, недолговечное существо . Разбить сосуд - лишить жизни человека.

Comment: Иначе зачем "не дрогнет рука"? Так что сосуд - ТОЛЬКО вместилище - чего-то жидкого или сыпучего или в метафорич. смысле вместилище души=человек. Разбить сосуд клеветника=убить клеветника. Стрелы в псаломе действительно орудие смерти, оружие, но у Пушкина - то о каком оружии речь? Там о смерти клеветника.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, посмотрела я  комментарий Лотмана к "Евгению Онегину", неудачное у него толкование. В то же время  странные рассуждения  поэта-романтика, так легко  допускающего  убийство человека. Или  нравы тогда были другие, жизнь человеческая мало ценилась.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь фрагмент статьи из ПЦС *с примерами*. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Позвольте спросить, а что такое *ПЦСЯ*?

Comment: Простите за краткость и неточность. Полный церковно-славянский словарь (составитель Григорій Дьяченко) http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/index.htm